# cookie store expects conn.secret_key_base to be at least 64 bytes -- but it's already

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

in production I have this:

```
use Mix.Config

config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  secret_key_base: System.get_env("MYAPP_SECRET_KEY_BASE")
```

That value is set in /etc/environment and is long enough, I've created it from "mix phoenix.gen.secret". However, it still throws an error:

```
** (exit) an exception was raised:
        ** (ArgumentError) cookie store expects conn.secret_key_base to be at least 64 bytes
            (plug) lib/plug/session/cookie.ex:159: Plug.Session.COOKIE.validate_secret_key_base/1
            (plug) lib/plug/session/cookie.ex:152: Plug.Session.COOKIE.derive/3
            (plug) lib/plug/session/cookie.ex:103: Plug.Session.COOKIE.put/4
            (plug) lib/plug/session.ex:92: anonymous fn/3 in Plug.Session.before_send/2
            (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1755: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
            (plug) lib/plug/conn.ex:961: Plug.Conn.run_before_send/2
            (plug) lib/plug/conn.ex:392: Plug.Conn.send_resp/1
            (my_app) web/controllers/home_controller.ex:1: MyApp.HomeController.action/2
```

Comment: Try to just `IO.inspect Application.get_env(:my_app, MyApp.Endpoint)` for starters.

Comment: @mudasobwa, it print my public config

Comment: @mudasobwa, actually the "secret_key_base" is the old, short one. but it doesn't even exist anymore in my project, I've done a search in files. And I've re-deployed it. Where is it retrieving it from?

Comment: What are you using to build/deploy the app @Jerry?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you set the value before compiling the application?

If you use `System.get_env("...")` inside of your configuration, then this value is retrieved at compile time. If you do things in the following order, then it is possible that the environment variable value you expect won't be used:

1. Set the config
2. Compile the application
3. Set the environment variable
4. Run the application

You can validate if this is the issue by running `mix compile --force`.

If the steps were executed in the following order, then the correct environment variable will be used.

1. Set the environment variable
2. Set the config
3. Compile the application
4. Run the application

Comment: That value is set in /etc/environment and is long enough,

Comment: @Jerry I did not dispute that the value was set. Did you try force compiling as I suggested? Also try `rm -rf _build` if that doesn't work.